# Initializing interleaved Arrays in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'd like to create a custom Array in Kotlin.

```
class Node(val point: Point) {
    var neighbour : Array<Node?> = Array(4, {_ -> null})
    var prev : Byte = -1
}
```

Now, in another class, I tried to create an object like:

```
class OtherClass{
    var field: Array<Array<Node?>> = Array(size.x, {_ -> Array(size.y, {_ -> null})})
    }
```

So basically, I need a Grid of Nodes, all initialized with null. The provided sizes are of type Integer.

I get the following error:
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:
required: Array< Array< Node?>>
found: Array< Array< Nothing?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin has an [`arrayOfNulls`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) function which might make this a bit more elegant:

```
val field: Array<Array<Node?>> = Array(4) { arrayOfNulls<Node?>(4) }
```

Or, without optional types:

```
val field  = Array(4) { arrayOfNulls<Node?>(4) }
```

I still have to specify `Node?` as the innermost type, however.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the solution was quite simple:

```
var field: Array<Array<Node?>> = Array(size.x, {_ -> Array(size.y, {_ -> null as Node?})})
```